# What would be TTL on records if we open DB multiple times with same TTL?

Tags: ttl, rocksdb

As per [Time To Live Documentation](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Time-to-Live):

> Open1 at t=0 with ttl=4 and insert k1,k2, close at t=2 Open2 at t=3
>   with ttl=5. Now k1,k2 should be deleted at t>=5

In my use case:

1. If I open the Rocksdb with ttl = 4 at t = 0
2. insert k1,k2.
3. Close the DB at t = 2.
4. Open DB again at t=4 with ttl=5
5. insert k1,k3.

**What would be ttl of k1,k2 and k3 now?** **Does TTL of records depend on opening DB multiple times?**

I was thinking ttl of all the records (k1,k2,k3) would be changed because we have opened DB multiple times even though with same TTL.